# NSNotificationCenter no event if user disables settings

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am implementing the 101 of Notification Center, with the simplest:

```
NSString *notif = @"notif";
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:notif
 object:self];
```

coupled with a

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(go)
                                             name:@"notif"
                                           object:nil];
```

If the user completely disables notifications for the app in the settings (no banner, no alerts), then the method GO will never be called. If user enables notifications, it will be called... 
What am I missing here? (I don't intend to do local push notifications with this code here - just internal code...)

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications and `NSNotificationCenter` are unrelated technologies. One does not affect the other.

`NSNotificationCenter`'s behavior can't be changed using Settings.app.

Comment: It makes sense to me - however how can you explain the behaviour/bug I have?

Comment: NSNotifications are 'programming concept' -- localNotifications show a UI